# Trying to copy files with certain a date from folders into another location with a mirrored folder structure

Tags: powershell, robocopy, xcopy

We're on sort of a file timecrunch. There are a bunch of files from 4/9/2019 that we need out of a bunch of directories. Every directory has ~1000 files. We want to copy all those files from 4/9/2019 to their respective folder structures, but only those files.

We used xcopy to copy the folder structure and have been manually copying the files we need. However, there are 1000 folders each with ~1000 files so it makes quite the hurdle. Tried passing on our arguments to copy-item, but it hasn't been giving me much luck.

I'm assuming even with my garbled code that there's some easy parameter or something I overlooked. We've been working through break and I've browsed through many topics and am turning to the community for help. I probably passed my exact problem on the way here.

For the record I don't code and use PowerShell infrequently.

```
#Gets all files that were last modified on 4/9/2019
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date -month 4 -day 9 -Format d) -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date -month 4 -day 10 -Format d)}) |

#Copies the files from source to destination
Copy-Item "C:\abc\" "D:\abc\"

}
```

Comment: The first thing you might want to use is `-WhatIf` switch on `Copy-Item`. That will tell you what would happen if it was done.

Comment: robocopy has older/newer options for file copy/move operations. when you have more than a few files, powershell is NOT the correct tool - robocopy is.

Comment: Lee_Dailey is correct. There are various cases where the older utilities such as Robocopy just do a better job and are simpler to use for these kinds of tasks.

Comment: Is there a way to get a specific day out of robocopy? Tried with that and xcopy but always grabbed more files than intended or no files at all. I've tried maxage, minage, xo and xn with no success. Any robocopy tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with [datetime] type variables don't apply `-format D` this converts to a  string,
instead strip the time component by appending `.Date` to both sides and test for equality.

As you are recursing the source into subfolders, you can't specify a flat target

```
$Source = "C:\abc\" 
$Target = "D:\abc\"
$MyDate = (Get-Date -Month 4 -Day 9 -Year 2019).Date

Get-ChildItem -Path $Src -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq $MyDate} | ForEach-Object{
        $TargetDir = $_.DirectoryName.replace($Source,$Target)
        If (!(Test-Path $TargetDir)){New-Item $TargetDir -ItemType Directory|Out-Null}
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $TargetDir
    }
```

Untested, you might append the `-WhatIf` parameter to `Copy-Item` while testing.

Robocopy is for sure faster, once you've found the right parameters.